# Set dropdown value using text value

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, import, eav

I have a small import script that will import product to Magento 1.

It works well but there is something not work.If a product attribute happen to be a select type attribute the value will not save.  I can determine this cause through eav system and magento would like to have the option id and not text value.

I have:

```
$product->setColour('red')->save();
```

But magento want:

```
$product->setColour(22)->save();
```

Is a method in magento that will accept the text value and correctly set the option id in the background for me?

Answer (score 11):

This is untested but should work:

```
$colourId = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("colour")->getSource()->getOptionId("red");
$product->setColour($colourId)->save();
```

Comment: It works. Very nice .

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using below mentioned code:

```
<?php
$attrId = attributeValueExists('color', 'red');
$product->setData('color', $attrId);
$product->save();

function attributeValueExists($argAttribute, $argValue)
{
    $attributeModel        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attributeOptionsModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attributeCode         = $attributeModel->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $argAttribute);
    $attribute             = $attributeModel->load($attributeCode);

    $options               = $attributeOptionsModel->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $argValue) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Just use `attributeValueExists('attribute_code','attribute text value')` this function in your code.Hope it will help you.